# How do I fix my nav so that it shows properly for mobile devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the nav on [my web page](http://hoteldemo.t15.org/responsive/html/) to respond properly to display on mobile devices.  There are three nav elements the "Home" link should be displayed underneath the brand name but instead it shows beside it.

Here's an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBKyv2OqdLoS0op2ic8W?p=preview)

```
<body>
        <div class="navbar wlt-navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">White Label Travel</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may want to create a `Fiddle` (https://jsfiddle.net/) and reproduce with the key elements extracted.  That will help eliminate some complexity and SO users won't have to click on your web site link which may or may not be secure.

Comment: You're right, I added a plnkr :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add header div for White Label Travel like this

```
<div class="navbar wlt-navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">White Label Travel</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li></li>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cjUNTagcCax1dROl19q?p=preview) is a Plunke...

GL!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

Use `.clearfix` on your code,the `visible-xs` class wroks on only mobile device....

```
<div class="navbar wlt-navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">White Label Travel</a>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```